# child themes style not apply in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, css, parent-child-theme

I have create child themes and select child themes, have style(style-l.css,style-m.css) not able to apply for this theme and site has been messed up.

Comment: Have you static-content deploy ?

Comment: yes,but did not call in child themes